# Entity framework context enrichments

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a base context:

```
public partial class BaseDbContext:DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<SlimPerson> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(IDbModelBuilderDecorator modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SlimPersonConfiguration());
    }
}
```

that has the table SlimPerson and its configuration.

I want to be able to use this context, but also use another context that inherits from this one and enriches it with new tables.

```
public MyContext: BaseDbContext
{
    public new IDbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(IDbModelBuilderDecorator modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
    }
```

}

of course Person: SlimPerson and SlimPersonConfiguration: PersonConfiguration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting one , what happens when you run this code?
Have you added Base.OnModelCreating(IDbModelBuilderDecorator modelBuilder) on the "MyContext" overriden method?

Comment: of couse. But it seems like you can't add two configurations on one table. Somehow the PersonConfiguration should enrich the SlimPersonConfiguration.

Comment: does  the PersonConfiguratiom extend the SlimPersonConfiguration?

Comment: yes, person config extends slim person config